# List adapters as activity class members

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I find it convenient to store list adapters as class members in my activities. The reason for this is that I can call the "invalidate" methods on it when i update my data, and the list will refresh.

How will this approach work when the activity state is serialized/moved out of memory and back in, will I need to reconstruct the adapter in onRestoreInstanceState to make my app behave well?

I can of course keep the data as class members and re construct the adapter from the data on activity state serialization/deserialization.

I can also keep my Listview as a class member and use getAdapter().notify... when I change the data.

Can anyone point me in the direction of "best practice" regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they will be restored. I've used the same thing in many projects and I've had no problem. You should take care though if you do the same thing to UI objects so that you don't end up with leaked memory.

Comment: So, you say that Android applications can leak memory if I keep UI objects as Activity class members, but Adapters should be fine?

Comment: Yes. Imagine that you keep a member with a reference to a button. When the device orientation changes the whole UI is discarded and redrawn (onCreate is called again). Your button is not discarded because you still have a reference to it. Or, imagine that you pass the Activity as an argument to a constructor for some object and the object lives longer than the activity. The activity will not be collected (even after you stop using it and the device runs low on memory) until that object is collected first.